# Problem with JPA Order By and swedish characters

Tags: jpa

I am experiencing a problem with order by in a JPA-query. The query is trivial and behaves as expected in an sql-client. The problem is the swedish characters å, ä and ö (should be in that order). When running the query through JPA (Hibernate) å and ä are in the wrong order (ä,å,ö).

There is no difference between Oracle and HslqDB and no difference between my local Windows PC and a Linux machine in the test environment.

I have tried a standard JPA-query, native JPA-query, native Hibernate query and the Hibernate criteria API. The order is wrong in all cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into what is called 'collation' in the Database world. I know that Oracle supports many different languages and will then correctly process your ORDER BY clause.

Look for information in the oracle documentation about possible values for the Oracle NLS_SORT session variable. I found [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#i1008393)

Set your collation like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = SWEDISH
```

Then run your query on the oracle prompt. If you make sure that you set this for every connection you should be fine.

So the problem does not lie with JPA/Hibernate or even JDBC.

Comment: The order is correct when running the query in an sql-client. When I run it through the application (JPA) the order gets altered. The same problem exists when using HSQL (in-memory-mode) which default use UTF-8.

Comment: The character encoding (UTF-8) is not really related to this problem.

You have to remember that when using JPA, every connection is a 'oracle session'. every connection gets created with default environment var values. Therefore, NLS_SORT is probably not set to the value that you want (SWEDISH). So you need to make sure that NLS_SORT is set correctly before executing a query that requires swedish alpabetical collation.

As far as HSQLDB is concerned, it has a different way of setting collation. See here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#collation-section

Comment: Ok, got it working now. Specifying the nls_sort and using the function nlssort did the trick.
Select * from adress order by nlssort(name, 'nls_sort = SWEDISH'). I would however prefer if it sould be set att the database level as default or if that is not possible as a connection parameter on the jdbc-url. Thank you.

Comment: I think that should be possible, but you'll have to look it up in the Oracle documentation. The use-case I had for it a few years ago was a bit different

Answer (score 0):

Which hibernate dialect are you specifying? That might make a difference. Here's an [article](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/08/14/how-to-set-the-default-charset-to-utf-8-for-create-table-when-using-hibernate-with-java-persistence-annotations/) that touches on related issues (albeit for Mysql).

Comment: I am using Oracle10gDialect for Oracle and HSQLDialect for HSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JPA with dbcp pool.

To me NLS_SORT could be modified using JAVA_OPTS parameter "user.language".

In my enviroment the value -Duser.language=pt solved the problem.

Comment: It works, how I can do it globally without adding any option ? For ex; from jpa or application properties, etc.